# Pass CFCObject.class as an argument to java method from Coldfusion

Tags: java, orm, coldfusion

I'm trying to run the following code...

```
ormSession = ORMGetSession();
result = ormSession.createSQLQuery("exec [dbo].[storedProcName] ")
                   .addEntity(MyModel.class)
                   .list();
```

MyModel is a coldfusion ORM cfc

How do I get the MyModel.class from MyModel.cfc to pass as the argument to addEntity()?

Comment: How are you defining `MyModel.class`?

Comment: I need MyModel.class from the cfc
`component accessors='true' persistent='true' table='MyModel' {...}`


I'm trying to call addEntity() from Coldfusion
[link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html#addEntity)

Comment: So your overall, the code is both ColdFusion and Java? Could we just have ColdFusion do all the ORM work then have Java read the DB?

Comment: I don't know that you can get the class name for a CFC. IIRC it returns something like "dummyComponent".